# Commutator Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Lets say that we know the value of the commutators [A,B] and [A,C]. Is there any way so that we can calculate value of commutator [B,C]? I looked up various sources for commutator identities, but somehow all of them fail to solve this.

Comment: Well, if $A=0$ then $[A,B]=0=[A,C]$. That can't really help you to say anything about $[B,C]$...

Comment: What if A is not equal to zero. Can we say anything about [B,C]?

Comment: Why the commutative algebra tag?

Comment: You should say that center of group doesn't contain $A$

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is in the centre of the group/Lie algebra (I don't know what the context is), then the first two commutators are trivial, while the third can be anything.

Comment: First two are already known.